# What's the difference among the logical relations :=, =, and ≡?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

I understand that ≡ is [logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence), "iff". '=' is a symbol for numerical equivalence. And ':=' is an identity claim. I often only see '=' and ':=' used with variables and names, while ≡ only appears with [predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_variable). I'm not sure if this is just from my limited exposure to logic or an actual convention. What's the big difference if we were to say 'a=b' vs 'a≡b'?. Or, for that matter, 'Px:=Qy'?

Comment: Can you give an example of := in usage?  I like others, have seen := used in programming languages, but I have not seen bare logic.  I'd love to see an example of it used in a document describing logic; I'd love to see the precursors to its use in programming.  For me, := has always been "assign a value/define" in programming only, = is "equal to" and ≡ is "same as" for situations where the word "equal" is not quite right.  I love symbology, so if there's a usage of := I've missed, I'd love to research it!

Comment: @CortAmmon - you can see it in Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA58) (5th ed - 2013), page 58.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no strict universally accepted convention.

In mathematical logic, **≡** is *logical equivalence*, as you said, and it is a connective between *proposition* (in *propositional calculus*) or *formulae* (in predicate calculus).

Example :

> **(p → q) ≡ (¬p ∨ q)**.

Usually, **=** stands for *equality* and it is a binary relation between "objects", like *numbers* in arithmetic.

Example :

> **∀x (x+0 = x)**.

Finally, **:=** is derived from programming languages, and is used (less often then the two above) as an "assignment" function : "let x be ...".

Example :

> **ψ := (x = y)**, stand for : let the formula **ψ** be **(x = y)**.

---

*Note* : except for programming languages, **:=** is **not** usually a symbol of the (*object*) language, but of the *meta*-language, while the two above are usually symbols of the language.

But we have to use **=** also in *meta*-language contexts, e.g. to express the identity relation between expressions; we can avoid confusion according to the context, but in some "pedantic" cases we introduce a different *identity* symbol for the *meta*-language, like **≐**.

Comment: I've seen ≡ used for defining a variable, just like the same way we would use :=, in many books on mathematics...

Comment: Rather confusingly, some texts use ≡ for logical equivalence but many, particularly older ones, use it for material equivalence. That is a usage that goes all the way back to Principia Mathematica. Best just not to use it. I would suggest using ⊨⫤ or  ⫤ ⊨for logical equivalence and ↔ or ⊂⊃ for material equivalence.

Answer (score 5):

It depends of context. But, usually

- := is to define a objects from anothers. Usually one define variables from values, x:=7, and maps, f(x):=x+1. Many programming languages use = to do that, but Pascal language uses := to assign values.
- = is to compare two objects and ensure they have the same "identity". For instance, some programming languages use "==" to do that: a==b is true if previously we defined a:=2 and b:=2.
- ≡ have two interpretation. In logic it usually means "propositional equivalence", it a little subtlety; for instance, the existencial quantifier is "defined" $∃x P(x)≡¬∀ x P(x)$. Shortly, if a≡b you can put b where you see a, and vice versa.

Also, in algebra ≡ is the congrunce operator; for instance, a ≡ b mod n means a-b is multiple of n.